# Regex for email without spaces

Tags: javascript

```
("^[_a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~;]+(\\.[_a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~;]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$")
```

This is my `regex` for email field but I don't want to allow spaces in email. What I have to do please suggest me??

Comment: have a look at this https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: `-/` will likely not pass validation

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are trying to validate the email address as originating from a known domain, validating is practically impossible and bound to be frustrating for users with unusual addresses that your regex fails validation on.

For reference: https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Here is [your current regex compared against a list of valid and invalid email addresses](http://regexr.com/47tp8). As you can see, you failed to allow several, perfectly valid email addresses while still letting through around 30% of the invalid ones.

Comment: Do not use regex for email validation. It doesn't work. Use a front end library such as [mailcheck](https://github.com/mailcheck/mailcheck) to assist users when typing in their address but allow the user to enter what they want. Then send an email to that address and make the user click a link within that email to confirm it is a valid address.